# Metal man eats berries to avoid becoming a metal man

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember the title of a sci-fi story I read where a man crash-lands his plane into a valley full of a gas that slowly turns him into metal. To prevent this, he needs to eat berries that he finds on bushes throughout his journey across the valley.

Comment: It would help to know when you read it.  There's a [checklist of things that can help ID a story](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/20490) as well.

Comment: You may also want to look at changing your username. Some people find that term offensive. Unless you're from another country where it means "to slow"?

Comment: Your title doesn't quite make sense. What does it mean for a "metal man" to avoid "becoming a metal man". Is that first "metal" a typo?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This could be "[The Metal Man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54789)" (1928) by Jack Williamson, which is a story about a man turning into metal and does feature berries that are able to reverse the effect:

> When I looked again at my finger nails, the tips of metal had doubled
> in width...
>
> I plucked off a few of the purple berries and tasted them. They had a
> salty, metallic taste, and I thought that they would be valueless for
> food. But in pulling them I had inadvertently squeezed the juice from
> one upon my fingers, and when I wiped it off I saw, to my amazement
> and my inexpressible joy, that the rim of metal was gone from the
> finger nails it had touched. I had discovered a means of safety!

Per ISFDB, it was originally published in the December 1928 issue of *Amazing Stories*. The story can be [read online in the context of its original publication](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v03n09_1928-12_Missing_ibcbc_AK/page/n25), courtesy of archive.org.

Comment: Quite impressive that the answer to the question "What's this story about a metal man called?" is literally "The Metal Man".